# javascript: problem with combining function and if

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, embed

Ok, I have this code in Javascript:

```
function fullWin() {
    if (document.getElementById('embed').src = 'vid1.mov') {
        window.open('vid1.html');
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('embed').src = 'vid2.mov') {
        window.open('vid2.html');
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the embed source equal is to vid2.mov, the source changes to vid1.mov and vid1.html opens. I want that if the embed source is equal to vid2.mov, vid2.html opens and viseversa. For those who want to know the html code.

```
<object height="100%" width="100%">
    <embed id="embed" target="_top" src="Amelie.m4v" autostart="false" height="100%" width="100%" scale="tofit"></embed>
</object>
<div id="div8" onClick="fullWin()">Fullscreen</div>
```

Comment: How does this even work? In JavaScript, logical equality is checked by == (or better ===). Is this a typo? If not, try that first.

Comment: Next time, just insert your code, mark it and click the `{}` button. See also [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or the orange box next to the question textbox.

Comment: @Seiryuu: Basically that's the error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use two = signs not just one. Or better yet use three ===. [**More on comparison operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

- One equals sign is assignment, `var a = 1;`
- Two is a type conversion equate, `'0' == 0; // true, because '0' is converted to a number`
- Three is strict comparison,  `'0' === 0; // false, because one is a string and one is a number`

Comment: @Victor: You can accept an answer by clicking on the green checkmark next to it. This helps organize stack overflo and removes your question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Even fixing the comparison operator doesn't make it work per bobince's post below.

Answer (score 1):

> if (document.getElementById('embed').src = 'vid1.mov')

This wouldn't work even if properly using a comparison operator (`==` or `===`). The `src` property of an `<emed>` element returns a resolved absolute URL such as `http://www.example.com/vid1.mov` rather than the exact original attribute value.

You can use `getAttribute('src')` to get the literal attribute value, except that doesn't work on IE; `getAttributeNode('src').value` is a workaround there, or alternatively try `.endsWith('vid1.mov')`, or something like:

```
window.open(document.getElementById('embed').src.replace('.mov', '.html');
```

I'd suggest using HTML5 video with Flash fallback these days; `<embed>` is somewhat old-fashioned and problematic.